# Finding the z for z=f(x,y) in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a Data table that can be imported into '2d-lookup table' of simulink.
The rows and columns are not equally spaced.
How do i create a model which takes x,y as inputs and gives z as output just by interpolating from the table. (i.e. for x,y which are some values that are between the values in table, it should generate polynomial equation based on table values and take the inputs and give the result ).

I can get it using matlab curvefit app, but i am restricted to use simulink.

Comment: I am not so familiar with Simulink but what you are asking for sounds like `griddedInterpolant`. The idea would be to get the data into MATLAB and created a griddedInterpolant with it and use it somehow with Simulink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already almost did what you want.
Using Simulink 2-D lookup table let you interpolate data automatically:
[image: First example]
Look at this: I set not equally spaced data and this works fine! Table Data is your `z` function values. So just change `x,y` (in my example it's `u1,u2`) and you will get what you want. You can see it works for `(x,y) = [2 8]`.

Now, lets solve second problem - how to take sum of all `z` values?
Important moment here - what sum you want to get! You know, Simulink has a lot of different solvers with variable or fixed step. So, solving it with fixed step, for example, `dt = 0.2` will give you all answers for `t= 0, 0.2, 0.4, ...` and so on. It will interpolate you entering data and solve `z` for each and if you get sum here would it be what you want?
If yes, easiest way - is to use `Integrator` block. Something like this:
[image]

But! What if you want to solve this only for values, you set in your `x,y` in workspace ( `(1 1), (3 8) , (7 10)` pairs from your comment) and whats to get sum of 3 `z`s only? It;s a good another question, maybe it's harder than using 2d lookup tables :)

I will show one of many possible solutions:
go to *Configuration Parameters/Solver* and set *fixed step* with **step size = 1**. And use this:
[image]

you can see it shows you `101` but it must be `95` in your case (`1+24+70`)! It's due to the fact simulink solves it for `t = (0, 0)` too! Interpolating data for `t=0` give additional `6`. It solves easily - add in your `z` table values for `x,y = 0`.

Hope it's clear now!

Comment: Hey, thanks.. I have a question, why did you use ramp ?
i want simulink to take input from user or it should take input from workspace.
the ramps take slope as input, here in my case it should be a value. What block should i use to take input from user.

Comment: I can't get to computer now I will answer to your question at monday, ok?

Comment: No problem , can i ask you another question along with the above one.. If there are set of quires(x,y) going as an inputs and all the 'z' values should be summed to get a single Z(sum of all z).

Comment: If my x = [ 1 3 7], y = [ 1 8 10] and data table is [ 1 3 7, 8 24 56, 10 30 70] and if i pass (x,y)=(2,8) i should get z as 16..    similarly a set of x,y should calculate z and sum all the z..     That is all i want..

Comment: @RanjithReddyKalluri I used ramp just for example. We can use anything here. And `fromworkspace` block too. I added in my answer information about calculations of sum of z! Check it!

Comment: in the answer you were saying about time step right?. I have few more questions regarding that. lets say my quiry data is associated with time/frequency. and lets say frequency varies for different run.. and if want to look at only a certain range data associated with during the run. How can we do that ?

Comment: Do you mean, your data step in your quires(x,y) can change for different simulations? I think we need to change time step in Simulink Configuration (for example, there are matlab function to set different Simulink parameters before run it) OR change scheme to make it  more multi-purpose. I think for detail approach we need more data - some your examples with specific numbers. I suggest you to create new question and describe this problem in details. Thus we would take not only my opinion but maybe someone can give more useful solution!

Comment: Hello Sam, i posted another question at the following link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35286511/5886342)