# Modeling a lookup table in simulink, which should pass the quires w.r.t time and also be able to get results only for certain time periods

Tags: matlab, interpolation, simulink, intervals

My data for lookup table is in the following image. lets say that first column is my Breakpoint 1, firts row is breakpoint 2 and other cells are my table data. 
[image: My data table]

Lets say I want to pass the following `x,y` values w.r.t
And I want the model to calculate for only few of them(e.g. I want to calculate for 4-7 values of `x,y` only)

[image: x,y queries w.r.t time]

after passing the above x,y values my output file is[image: Result]

I want to pass data points for each time step, not like all data points for all time steps

If we look at the output file of the subsystem the result is being added to the previous data point.[image: output from subsystem]

It actually should pass only one data point at a timestep, the result should be added to the value from previous data point.

Comment: while thinking about your example, i get one more idea - what if you add additional parameter for your table and give to it time in simulink? (for example 1-D for x, 2-D for y and 3-D would be for t ! ) 
And its be clearer if you add some numeric examples i think

Comment: Ok, show your quires and how it depends on time. And show your current table. why it became N-D from 2-D?

Comment: The data table we have is not w.r.t time, the quires which we pass are.
Eg:  let row = 1 5 10 , column = 2 6 9, data in page 1 =
 2 10 20
6 30 60
9 45 90
and data in page 2 is 
3 7 12
7 11 16
10 14 19

rows and columns are same for both the data.. But the operation done in first page is multiplication, second one is addition.
Now if a want to pass  x=1,2,3... y = 1,2,3... for time = 1,2,3.. 
I want both operations done for all values of time or from 3-5 sec..

Comment: ok, I add your data from comment to your question to everyone can see it, Is it right? Now two new questions: first of all - how you realized that first page multiplaing and then adding to second page?? And the second: do you still have constant timestep? Is it always `1`?

Comment: actually that is just to give as an example, my actual data is extracted from so many sensors and cant put that data in here.
secondly yes, its a constant time step.. but not always 1.. can we model such that it ask's for user to define it prior to complete the run ?

Comment: ok. about multiplication and adding: can we create 2 lookup tables? both of them interpolate needed values and then summarise it? Or if you already done this, can you show this part of your simulink model?
Or show please what result we would get for this example data

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam   Yeah, actually n-d lookup table cant be used, so i've created two 2-d lookup table, one for each operation. i think we can't do much about it..
Now the problem is how to give w.r.t time.  How should take queries wrt time.

e.g. I have 100 query points at frequency of 10 hertz. i.e each query point is for 0.1 sec or 10 points per sec.. 
Lets say all my query points are in order, how do i pass query points only from 3-6 sec ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make some workaround your problem and here my approach:

first of all let see how to calculate sum only for specific interval. I suggest to use [Enabled subsystem block](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/enabled-subsystems.html). It works only when it activated by the signal. make specific signal for your time interval is easy. There are a lot of ways. For example, you can go this way:

[image]
 `1` and `0.5` are limits for your time interval. 
Now only for our this time Subsystem will work and will summarize your data. Subsystem:
[image]

---

I checked this for your data:

```
 xy_data =

 1   650    50
 2   675    70
 3   700    90
 4   725   110
 5   750   130
 6   775   150
 7   800   170
 8   825   190
 9   850   210
10   875   230
```

Data in Lookup table:
[image]

And I get result `228`. (you can see result at **Display2 into Subsystem**).
I checked it step by step and looks like it works correct (it's really close to table values!).

To get values of `z` at each timestep just add `to workspace` block after lookup table like this:
[image]

Now, if you calculate sum of 4-5 secs you will get my result `228` (227.9903 actually - it just rounded).
Why I put `Unit Delay` block here: it is necessary for calculation SUM - to get sum you need take current value and add to sum from previous step. To get signal value from previous step you have to use Unit Delay.

---

Second question about timestep. If you dont want to change it manually, you can do it by some MATLAB commands from your workspace. You can write script for example, and change only timestep value in it.

```
mdl = 'NameOfSimulinkModel'           %your model name
open_system(mdl);                     % open it in visible mode
configSet = getActiveConfigSet(mdl)   % load all parameters of model
s = configSet.getComponent('Solver')  % get handle at Solver parameters

s.getProp('FixedStep')                % get current step value
s.setProp('FixedStep', '0.1')         % set needed value
sim(mdl)                              % start simulation in Simulink
```

So you see your data, calculate needed value of time step, set it from Command Window and start simulation.

Hope it helps!
Here is last version of my model: [here](http://www.filedropper.com/lookupexample_2).

Comment: @RanjithReddyKalluri, last picture is the subsytem. You can ask me in Matlab chat here at SO: [MatlabChat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab-and-octave)

Comment: I dont have enough reputation in here to enter the conversation. Let's continue in here..

Comment: I vote up your question, You'll have 7 more reputation now 9need 20 to enter chat room). But it's ok, if you have some questions - ask here!

Comment: Actually if you see my question again, I've edited the last part of it again.
will the model you suggested here work if my queries are as i mentioned. ?

Comment: Yep! I just checked it: it works! I set stoptime = 10 and stepsize = 1. I load your data, run simulation and get this: `z` values for steps 4-7 : `187 260 345 442`. And this Display2 into subsystem shows `1234` - it's a sum of all of them. 
I need to remember, that I used your `z` table, but it has not breakpoints for `x,y` more then 10 and 9. SO Simulink extrapolate your values of queries!

Comment: where did you enter the stop time ?
When i run the model for my actual values, it gave me the following errors

An error occurred while running the simulation and the simulation was terminated

Assertion detected in 'untitled1/Check  Dynamic Gap' at time 0.5
Component: Simulink | Category: Block error

Comment: If you can say me how it worked for you to get 4-7, thats i all i would need.. Thank you, for your patience ..

Comment: In this time I set timestop in simulink manually, but you really can do it from matlab by using `s.setProp('stoptime', '10')` if you need.

Ah yes, sorry I forgot to pay attention at this moment: open `Chech Dynamic Gap` block. Put off `Stop simulation when assertion fails` and put on `output assertion signal`

Comment: I've edited that check dynamic gap block..
I've given the max value as 10 and min as 1 and run the model., It gave the error with assertion in the block, and my out is not the correct answer.

Comment: I've posted the question again with some of my original data at the following link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35333874/5886342)

Comment: @RanjithReddyKalluri I add link in my answer. Download my example model and check it. If it wouldn't help you, ask here again

Comment: It's the same model as your answer, but it's giving me the wrong answer..
In my new question, I've given some of my original data.. can you please check it at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35333874/5886342)

Comment: hmmm. How you know it's wrong? Table calculates `z`. Summarize it only for 4-7 secs. What is working wrong?

Comment: In my actuall data i passed only two values of queries , the answer should be around in hunderds but the answers i got was in 100,000 so its wrong

Comment: wait wait wait. Check it for my data! if it's ok, then problem not in model :)

Comment: if you not sure what is wrong, put your real data here in your question and what you need to get. I will check it one more time )

Comment: If you look at the data in the other question, just pass two values to lookup  table without having any loops.. You'll know what the answers are supposed to be, and lets have the time loop and see if they are same..

Comment: edit data here. what we really need to use. And what want to see. Lets try again. But you must understand, that if it works for my data it must for you data too. Just some mistake in calibration or in setting table data

Comment: Sam, in the model you sent i forgot to change my data, after changing it, i still get the assertion at the check dynamic gap block..
More over the data displayed after lookup table is not the same that we are getting in the subsystem.  and i tried the code you typed in the answer, it dint give expected results aswell.

Comment: and why did we have delay block in the subsystem, and i assume that this delay block is causing all the error.

Comment: @RanjithReddyKalluri do you set off `stop simulation when assertion fails` in the Dynamic Gap Block? check this option! 
delay block returns signal from PREVIOUS TIMESTEP. We need it to take a sum.

Comment: Another issue raised up while working on this, All the data points going in for lookup table are passed all at a time, I had a output file which is all my data points in the columns and time in the rows, I'll upload a pic of it.

Comment: @RanjithReddyKalluri I checked it one more time for your correct data and it works! I add information to my answer. one more thing - looks like you use timestep = 0.1 (from you results). It must be `1` here according your input data. Maybe you got some problems to put data in lookup table. Check my example careful! If you will need it, i will add example of model with your values to my answer .

Comment: I got what you are talking about.. Your answer did work but i've few questions in them too. I'll add another pic which i got from your subsystem as output....  **bold** can i send each data point at  each time step, instead of all data points at every time step (this one as in my output).. Secondly from the subsystem can you explain what the unit delay is actually doing, i don't think we need that..

Comment: How you get this results? I tried `to workspace` block and simple `out` block but I can't get  this table. I got only one column of values. 
Second - my example already calculates SUM. So if you want to get values of `z` for each timestep - just add `to workspace` block after lookup table. If you want your result as you asked before (sum of 4-7 sec) - use final value in subsystem. Info about this I add to my answer.

Comment: @Mikahil_Sam   May be because i am using two 'from workspace' block to pass x,y i am getting the issue.
to use single block to pass both the values, what is the format that your variables are & is that a demux after 'from workspace' ?

Comment: I attached it to answer :) look at this carefully. I'm sure you problem is due to wrong way to place data in lookup table. Here in my program is text. Just cope it and put in matlab to create xy_data variable. then simulate this. This works perfectly. You just need to understand working principle.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer! I hope it's a sign that you done what you want!

Comment: Thank you sam for the help.. the answer worked for 10 data points. I have created similar model, there cameup some errors.
But while your model worked if it edit the data.

Comment: Just be careful when loading data in model - some practice and you can get it for any data :)